# How to add a class to element when it is loaded by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, accordion, addclass

I am having trouble using a jquery plugin with content that is loaded by Ajax. I was given the following example to follow but don't know how to change the code in my case because it has multiple functions like addClass, find and click.

In this example, an alert would pop up if you click the element. But this would not work on the elements, which are loaded via ajax into the DOM.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
  jQuery( 'p' ).click( function(){ alert( 'hello' ); });
});
```

You would need something like

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
  jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', 'p', function(){ alert( 'hello' ); });
});
```

If I have the line:

```
jQuery('.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle')
  .addClass('omsc-in-accordion')
  .find('.omsc-toggle-title')
  .click(function(){
```

How would I change that?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your line after you appending code, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/my-action",
  success: function(response) {
    $("body").append(response);

    $('.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle')
        .addClass('omsc-in-accordion')
        .find('.omsc-toggle-title')
        .click(function(){
           ...
        });

  }  
});
```

but for me it doesn't make sense to handle something after addClass.. anyway.. It could work :)